# Apache Storm Starter 2.2.0 in Eclipse in Windows - Exception while trying to get leader nimbus info from localhost NimbusLeaderNotFound

Tags: eclipse, maven, apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

I have downloaded the zip file for Apache Storm 2.2.0.
I imported the storm-starter maven project into eclipse in Windows 10. Did a Maven--> Update Project
My project did not have any errors. I did not do any updates to pom.xml.
I executed the WordCountTopology.java
I get the error NimbusLeaderNotFoundException.
I tried after stopping firewall also.

```
00:54:00.584 [main] INFO  o.a.s.StormSubmitter - Generated ZooKeeper secret payload for MD5-digest: -xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
00:54:00.668 [main] WARN  o.a.s.v.ConfigValidation - task.heartbeat.frequency.secs is a deprecated config please see class org.apache.storm.Config.TASK_HEARTBEAT_FREQUENCY_SECS for more information.
00:54:16.923 [main] WARN  o.a.s.u.NimbusClient - Ignoring exception while trying to get leader nimbus info from localhost. will retry with a different seed host.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient.reconnect(ThriftClient.java:108) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient.<init>(ThriftClient.java:69) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.<init>(NimbusClient.java:80) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:221) [storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:179) [storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(NimbusClient.java:138) [storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.blobstore.NimbusBlobStore.prepare(NimbusBlobStore.java:47) [storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.validateTopologyBlobStoreMap(Utils.java:1178) [storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.validateConfs(StormSubmitter.java:530) [storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopologyAs(StormSubmitter.java:236) [storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:210) [storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:173) [storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.topology.ConfigurableTopology.submit(ConfigurableTopology.java:119) [storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.starter.WordCountTopology.run(WordCountTopology.java:58) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.storm.topology.ConfigurableTopology.start(ConfigurableTopology.java:68) [storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.starter.WordCountTopology.main(WordCountTopology.java:36) [classes/:?]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect.retryNext(TBackoffConnect.java:59) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect.doConnectWithRetry(TBackoffConnect.java:51) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient.reconnect(ThriftClient.java:98) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:226) ~[storm-shaded-deps-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:91) ~[storm-shaded-deps-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransportPlugin.connect(SimpleTransportPlugin.java:101) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect.doConnectWithRetry(TBackoffConnect.java:48) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient.reconnect(ThriftClient.java:98) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
    at org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:221) ~[storm-shaded-deps-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:91) ~[storm-shaded-deps-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransportPlugin.connect(SimpleTransportPlugin.java:101) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect.doConnectWithRetry(TBackoffConnect.java:48) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient.reconnect(ThriftClient.java:98) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    ... 15 more
org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusLeaderNotFoundException: Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts [localhost]. Did you specify a valid list of nimbus hosts for config nimbus.seeds?
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:250)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:179)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(NimbusClient.java:138)
    at org.apache.storm.blobstore.NimbusBlobStore.prepare(NimbusBlobStore.java:47)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.validateTopologyBlobStoreMap(Utils.java:1178)
    at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.validateConfs(StormSubmitter.java:530)
    at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopologyAs(StormSubmitter.java:236)
    at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:210)
    at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:173)
    at org.apache.storm.topology.ConfigurableTopology.submit(ConfigurableTopology.java:119)
    at org.apache.storm.starter.WordCountTopology.run(WordCountTopology.java:58)
    at org.apache.storm.topology.ConfigurableTopology.start(ConfigurableTopology.java:68)
    at org.apache.storm.starter.WordCountTopology.main(WordCountTopology.java:36)
```

Same Eclipse in Windows 10, Under a different eclipse project, For previous storm versions' code (Version 0.0.1) Zookeeper starts, nimbus starts fine. I am able to get the output.
I did not do any cluster configuration in local/eclipse.[Success Topology with version 0.0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A34hK.png)

Comment: What Java version are you using? Could be a problem related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-3779